# have all programs called by msbuild runas admin

Tags: msbuild, uac

Is there a way to launch msbuild so that it calls devenv.exe as admin? We need this because it registers COM assemblies as part of the build.

thanks - dave

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Msbuild does not call devenv.exe. Are you doing the build from VS IDE? If so, just launch the devenv.exe elevated (right click -> Run As Admin). If you build from command line, launch command window elevated.

Comment: In the .proj file we have calls to run devenv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way is to launch MSBuild.exe as administrator (such as running msbuild command at an elevated command prompt), then all processes initialized by it such as devenv.exe are running under administrator context.